# Error: "Missing \endcsname"

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, xsim

I have a problem when compiling my Latex file.
The problem seems to be the

- babel-package `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}` (because the error goes away if I delete this line)
- the xsim-package
- and the tikz code (the line `\pic[draw,thick,<-,angle radius=.7cm,"$\alpha$" opacity=1] {angle=p--o--px};`)

I get the error like: `Missing \endcsname inserted`

Maybe there are more than just one error. Can you help me to get rid of the error?

Edit:
I've tried to use `use-files`, as well as `\AtBeginEnvironment{auf}{\shorthandoff{"}}`. They did not work but `\shorthandoff{"}` and `\shorthandon{"}` worked in the end.

Interestingly I can compile the file with an older Mac (and an older version of TeXShop).

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,babel,3d}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{needspace}
\DeclareExerciseType{auf}{
exercise-env= auf,
solution-env= lsg,
exercise-name=Aufgabe ,
solution-name= Losung,
exercise-template= default ,
solution-template= default}

\begin{document}
\begin{auf}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,font= \footnotesize]
\newcommand\rr{1.2};
\newcommand\angl{-30};
\draw (0,0) coordinate(o) circle (\rr);
\draw[->] (-\rr*1.2,0) -- (\rr*1.2,0) coordinate(px) coordinate (x axis) node[below] {$x$}; 
\draw (o) -- ({\angl}:\rr) coordinate(p) ++ (0:{\rr*cos(\angl)});
\pic[draw,thick,<-,angle radius=.7cm,"$\alpha$" opacity=1] {angle=p--o--px};
 \draw[domain=0:-360,thick,samples=50] plot ({cos(\x)*(0.6-0.1*\x/360)}, {sin(\x)*(0.6-0.1*\x/360)});
\draw[fill=white] (p) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$P$};
\draw[fill=black] (p) circle (0.3pt);
\draw[->] (0,-\rr*1.2) -- (0,\rr*1.2) coordinate (y axis) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{auf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `no ; in nullfont` are from the semicolon after the new commands definition, which are wrong.

Comment: Thanks, the semicolon are indeed the reason for the ```no ; in nullfont``` error. Nevertheless @WillieWong: Your source does not help, I have tried ```\AtBeginEnvironment{exercise}{\shorthandoff{"}}``` and ```use-files``` and both did not work. I will edit my question.